# Is there a way I can declare these groups only once?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am writing tests in Java with TestNG & Selenium.

I am having to list these groups over & over to ensure these methods get executed:

```
@BeforeSuite(groups = { "all", "simple", "smoketest", "login", "layers", "networks", "basemaps", "jobs",
        "inspections", "defects", "projects", "teams", "routes", "search", "schedules", "gateway", "permissions",
        "mesh", "designer", "workflow", "reports", "streetlighting", "collections", "wip", "deletes", "views",
        "create", "edit" })
```

and again:

```
@BeforeTest(groups = { "all", "simple", "smoketest", "login", "layers", "networks", "basemaps", "jobs",
        "inspections", "defects", "projects", "teams", "routes", "search", "schedules", "gateway", "permissions",
        "mesh", "designer", "workflow", "reports", "streetlighting", "collections", "wip", "deletes", "views",
        "create", "edit" })
```

Is there a way I can declare all these groups only once, as this is a source of errors?

Comment: You can create a group of groups. - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#groups-of-groups

Comment: Thank you @Grasshopper. That worked!

Comment: @Grasshopper - You might want to add that as an answer so that Steve can accept it and the question gets closed.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I am not sure about this. This appeared to work until I ran a large suite on our test server. Most of the TestNG annotated methods were not called, as they should have been. The details of that test are too big to present here. When I get a chance I will retest these.

Comment: Check if you have added a `alwaysRun=true` to your config methods so that they get executed irrespective of which group you select for test execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a **group of groups** in the testng.xml file. Refer to this for more details - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#groups-of-groups